# Need to set variables to "Null" after POST action (PHP function)

Tags: php, html

I have a comments section in a website that uses a "setComments" function to enter data into a SQL DB. This works great, but I found that if I refresh the page, the comment is re-entered into the DB and displayed as multiple comments using a "getComments" function.

I know I need to drop the values of the comment variables but tried a few places in the code and no joy.

This is the form to enter the comment:

```
    <?php
        echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
          <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
          <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='$post_id'>
          <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
          <label>Add Comment</label>
          <textarea name='message'class='form-control' width='50' cols='40' 
    rows='3'></textarea><br>
          <button type = 'submit' name ='commentSubmit' class='btn btn- 
   primary'>Submit<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span> 
   </button>
        </form>";

        getComments($conn)

         ?>



    <?php
    function setComments($conn){
      if (isset($_POST ['commentSubmit'])) {
        $uid=$_POST['uid'];
        $pid=$_POST['pid'];
        $date=$_POST['date'];
        $message=$_POST['message'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, pid, date, message) 
    VALUES('$uid','$pid', '$date', '$message')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        }
    }

    function getComments($conn) {
      if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
        $pid = $_GET['post'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE pid=$pid";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<div class='comment-box'>";
          echo $row['uid']."<br>";
          echo $row['date']."<br>";
          echo $row['message'];
        echo "</div>";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "Be the first to comment";
    }
    }
    }
```

Comments are entered into sql DB fine, but variables not discarded once complete so they are re-entered into DB and displayed again on page refresh (page containing the comment form also displays the comments.

Comment: Are you sure that by "refreshing" you don't mean "resubmitting the form"? (check the HTTP request when you "refresh" your page).

Comment: You are correct, but not sure what you mean by "check HTTP request", what will this show me?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following script in the page - it seems to work fine:

```
<script>
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}
</script>
```